# Store the date in R

Tags: r, date

I just want to change the "datalist[[1]]"(a dataframe, the V2 and V3 of it are date and time) into the date format

```
 time<-apply(datalist[[1]],1,function(data){
  #set the locale time to meet the format
  Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME","English")  
  t_date<-paste(data[2],data[3],sep=" ");
  s_date<-as.POSIXct(t_date,format="%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S");
  print(s_date);
  return(s_date)  
})
```

when I print the `s_date`, it shows like format `2013-11-03 14:23:37 CST`; But when I print `time` (the aggregation of all the result), it shows like format `383472300`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `paste` the columns without using the `apply` loop

```
with(datalist[[1]], as.POSIXct(paste(V2, V3),
                         format='%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S'))
#[1] "2001-08-01 03:15:25 EDT" "2005-09-20 10:12:09 EDT"
```

Or

```
as.POSIXct(do.call(paste, datalist[[1]][-1]), format='%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S')
#[1] "2001-08-01 03:15:25 EDT" "2005-09-20 10:12:09 EDT"
```

`apply` coerces 'POSIXct' class to 'numeric' as the object is not strictly vector.  But, we can convert back the result to the intended class.

```
res <- apply(datalist[[1]], 1, function(data) {
      t_date <- paste(data[2], data[3], sep=" ")
      s_date <- as.POSIXct(t_date, format = '%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S')})

as.POSIXct(res, origin='1970-01-01')
#[1] "2001-08-01 03:15:25 EDT" "2005-09-20 10:12:09 EDT"
```

It may be better to use the first two ways instead of the `apply`

#### data

```
set.seed(25)
datalist <- list(data.frame(V1= rnorm(2), V2= c('01-Aug-01', 
          '20-Sep-05'), V3= c('03:15:25', '10:12:09')))
```